# HAML partial - error rendering the partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, partials

I have this line of code:

```
  = render :partial => "views/influencers/disclosures/shared/list"
```

and I am getting this error:

```
Missing partial views/influencers/disclosures/shared/list with {:locale=>[:en, :en], :handlers=>[:haml, :erb, :builder], :formats=>[:html]}. Searched in:
```

and the partial I am trying to render is in this directory:

```
app/views/influencers/disclosures/shared/_list.html.haml
```

and I am trying to call this partial from a file located here:

```
app/views/mobile/disclosures/index.html.haml
```

any idea why it wouldn't get recognized and why this error is happening?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace with:

```
= render :partial => "/influencers/disclosures/shared/list"
```